# IDE disk displaced SATA as 'secondary' or disk 1, Chameleon MacOS loader doesn't find com.apple.Boot.plist file now

Tags: macos, mac, boot, sata, bootloader

I have a SATA and an IDE disks, when I added the IDE disk, it was recognized as disk 0 and the SATA disk became disk 1.
Everything works perfectly, I can change the boot order from setup so it's ok.

The specific problem is, I have MacOS installed, with the Chameleon bootloader which looks for the com.apple.Boot.plist file to know what partition from what disk to load by default. As the file is now on disk 1 instead of disk 0, Chamelon seems to not find it, so it doesn't automatically boot but instead prompts for the user to select a partition.

Would using a jumper to set the disks master/slave solve the problem? the IDE disk is in the only IDE port of my motherboard, and I don't think this is a master/slave issue.

Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your motherboard is set to POST IDE devices first - thereby Chameleon recognizes your IDE hard disk as the first device.

It has nothing to do with boot order, but more rather in terms of the sequence your BIOS reports hard disks, e.g disk01, disk02, etc.

I suggest you find a way to edit Chameleon's boot preference files to boot from the SATA disk itself. That's another question, by the way. :)